# Angular 2, clear <router-outlet> after load component

Tags: angular

I have loader gif in my `<router-outlet>` selector in `template.html`.
When component load new template in `<router-outlet>`, template is append under a loader gif, I want to component overwrite loader gif.

Comment: The question would be easier to understand if you would add some code that demonstrates what you're doing.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think he wants `router-outlet` to behave like any other component. This means when component is loaded anything originally inside the tag is replaced by component content so user can see 'Loading...' while it´s not loaded. On the other hand `router-outlet` just appends the content instead of replacing it and he wants to get rid of the original content